# Boost.Interprocess: How to call and send data to a function from class that is in another process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, multiprocessing, boost-interprocess

So I have created a simple class that works for threads - you can add any void function of any class to a list of subscribed functions of a class that enherits from presented my class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

// parts of c++0x std
#include <boost/bind.hpp> 
#include <boost/function.hpp>

#ifndef _CoreEvents_h_
#define _CoreEvents_h_

using namespace std ;
template <typename DataType >
class CoreEvents{

        typedef boost::function<void(DataType)>   Function;
        typedef std::vector<Function>      FunctionSequence;
        typedef typename FunctionSequence::iterator FunctionIterator; 

public:
        DataType* dataElement;
        FunctionSequence funcs;
        boost::thread_group tg;

        CoreEvents()
        {
                dataElement = new DataType();
        }
        // Function for adding subscribers functions
        // use something like std::bind(&currentClassName::FunctionToAdd, this, std::placeholders::_1) to add function to vector
        void Add(Function f)
        {
                funcs.push_back(f);
        }

        // Cast data to subscribers and clean up given pointer
        //ToDo: One  will be solved when pool of pre-initialized objects will be developed 
        virtual void Cast(){
                for (FunctionIterator it(funcs.begin()); it != funcs.end(); ++it){
                        DataType dataCopy = *dataElement;
                        tg.create_thread(boost::bind(*it, dataCopy));
                }
        }  
};
```

All you need to subscribe is:

```
someClass->Add(boost::bind(&someOtherClass::someVoidFunction, this, _1));
```

This is simple when we deal with threads - we can always call for example create_thread and have all we need done in other app thread.

But what if we have app1 app2 and app3 and you want to share a pointer of a function form one process and using broker app give that pointer to another app so that it could be called with parameters from last process/app?

In real life it would look like if we had an app with not editable text feild running, and an app with editable text field running. and we had app №3 that could connect input from editable TF to not editable TF.

Is it possible with [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) and how to do such thing?

I am quite new to C++ but I think I found some [bad info related](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_region_object_limitations.references_forbidden):

> References forbidden
>
> References suffer from the same
>   problem as pointers (mainly because
>   they are implemented as pointers).
>   However, it is not possible to create
>   a fully workable smart reference
>   currently in C++ (for example,
>   operator .() can't be overloaded).
>   Because of this, if the user wants to
>   put an object in shared memory, the
>   object can't have any (smart or not)
>   reference as a member.
>
> References will only work if the
>   mapped region is mapped in the same
>   base address in all processes sharing
>   a memory segment. Like pointers, a
>   reference placed in a mapped region
>   should only point to an object of that
>   mapped region.
>
> Virtuality forbidden
>
> The virtual table pointer and the
>   virtual table are in the address space
>   of the process that constructs the
>   object, so if we place a class with a
>   virtual function or virtual base
>   class, the virtual pointer placed in
>   shared memory will be invalid for
>   other processes and they will crash.
>
> This problem is very difficult to
>   solve, since each process needs a
>   different virtual table pointer and
>   the object that contains that pointer
>   is shared across many processes. Even
>   if we map the mapped region in the
>   same address in every process, the
>   virtual table can be in a different
>   address in every process. To enable
>   virtual functions for objects shared
>   between processes, deep compiler
>   changes are needed and virtual
>   functions would suffer a performance
>   hit. That's why Boost.Interprocess
>   does not have any plan to support
>   virtual function and virtual
>   inheritance in mapped regions shared
>   between processes.
>
> Be careful with static class members
>
> Static members of classes are global
>   objects shared by all instances of the
>   class. Because of this, static members
>   are implemented as global variables in
>   processes.
>
> When constructing a class with static
>   members, each process has its own copy
>   of the static member, so updating a
>   static member in one process does not
>   change the value of the static member
>   the another process. So be careful
>   with these classes. Static members are
>   not dangerous if they are just
>   constant variables initialized when
>   the process starts, but they don't
>   change at all (for example, when used
>   like enums) and their value is the
>   same for all.

But I am creating all my apps using one same library. and when I need best performance I will use threading, but it happens that I need an interprocess communication. So what shall I do - how to create a mechanism to emulate much needed functionality?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this question is a bit hard to understand, but I'll try to answer.

Sharing function pointers between processes is something you should almost **never** do. It's very dangerous. Sharing non-primitive data is also frowned upon, but okay in some cases.

Generally, you should use something like messaging for this. You may want to use Boost.Interprocess to share parameters.

Comment: almost never... means it is possible... - I know its quite wary dangerous - I am willing to risk. How to do such thing?